# Record the sound and play the same sound at same time in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I want to record the sound and play the same sound through my application at same time.

Had recorded the sound :-

```
 NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];    
    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
        [audioRecorder record];
    }

-(void)StopRecord{
[audioRecorder stop];
 NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];  
    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
    [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error: nil];    
    if([soundFileURL isFileURL]){
        printf("isFileURL\n");
    }   
    [newPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [newPlayer setDelegate: self];
       [newPlayer play];

}
```

Now by this..i record the sound and when i click some method the recording get stop and start playing..What should i do..that it play the sound the same moment i start recording..

Comment: What do u exactly mean by "same moment i start recording". If it's still getting recording, how can you play?

Comment: audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"soundFilePath"] error:&error]; use this while playing audio

Comment: @murali I want to create the mic kind of application..The moment i say something..i will get reflected in the application.

Comment: sorry @shweta i am not getting u,can u pls tell me more abt it?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution by using SC_listner.

```
[[SCListener sharedListener] listen];   

   if ([SCListener sharedListener] != nil)
    {
        Float32 percentage = [[SCListener sharedListener] peakPower];
        }
```

By doing this..i get the detect the pitch of the real time

Comment: is this working for play small sound and Record the voice at same time in iphone